# R Data Table Alternating Row Color with Groupings

Tags: css, r, datatable, dt

I have a shiny dashboard with a data table in it that I would like to customize the alternating row colors. I was able to find the CSS to specify the odd and even row color but because I am using the RowGroup extension it is not working as intended. It is counting the group header as a row.

[image: Table with current css to customize alternating row colors]

The first row in the "Male" group should be white, not blue. Hoping this is a quick CSS fix. Thanks in advance!

Below is a short reproducible example:

```
### Short reproducable example for alternating rows in datatable
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(
  Sex = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male"),
  First.Name = c("Mary", "Amy", "Connor", "Blaine", "Emily"),
  Last.Name = c("Frazier", "Jones", "Jones", "Black", "Rains")
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard", 
                  titleWidth =300
  ),
  
  dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                   
                   sidebarMenu(id = "sidebar",
                               menuItem("User Guide", tabName = "userguide", icon = icon("question-circle")),
                               menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("table"), selected = TRUE)
                   )
                   
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "userguide",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12
                )
              )
      ),
      
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12, 
                    DTOutput("table") %>%
                      withSpinner(color = "#00416B")
                )
                
              )
      )
    )
    
  )
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    data,
    rownames = FALSE, 
    caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
      style = 'text-align: center; font-weight: bold; color:black',
      paste0("This list was generated on ", Sys.Date(), ".")
    ),
    extensions = c('Buttons', 'RowGroup', 'FixedHeader'),
    options = list(paging = FALSE, 
                   dom = 'Blft',
                   fixedHeader = TRUE,
                   buttons = list(
                     list(extend = 'pdf', 
                          filename = paste0("List ", Sys.Date()), 
                          orientation = 'landscape')
                   ),
                   rowGroup = list(dataSrc = 0),
                   initComplete = JS(
                     "function(settings, json) {",
                     "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#00416B', 'color': 'white'});",
                     "$('table.dataTable.display tbody tr:odd').css('background-color', 'white');",
                     "$('table.dataTable.display tbody tr:even').css('background-color', '#e4f0f5');",
                     "}")
                   
                   
    ),
    escape = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has already the classes odd and even assigned, you just "redo" that with the tr:odd and tr:even over the whole table again which causes the issue.

The fix is very simple, replace tr:odd and tr:even in your JS code to tr.odd and tr.even